# Finding the equation of the graph y=a^x +b from given points (2,5) and (0,-4)

Tags: graphing-functions, exponential-function

I am trying to figure out the equation of an exponential graph from two given points.

I know you have to plug each set of points into the equation, but I forget exactly how to solve this.

As stated in the question, the equation for the graph is y=a^x +b

Fist set of points: (2,5)

set of points with y intercept: (0,-4)

Thank you all.

Comment: Well, if you know you have to "plug", what equations does that give you?

Answer (score 1):

As you have said, just put the points into the equation:
\begin{align}
5 & = a^2 + b \\
-4  & = a^0 + b
\end{align}

The second equation directly gives you the first value you need, inserted into the first equation you can easily calculate $a$.

Comment: Technically, without an assumption that $a$ is positive (or that the graph should be some continuous function with domain $\mathbb R$) this doesn't determine $a$. But I'm absolutely certain that the author of the question (whether it was user115944 or not) either said $a$ is positive, or meant to.